# how we can paginate data on Laravel when we have a complex query

Tags: laravel

I have the following query on the Oracle database

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT to_char(to_date(t2.REGISTRATION_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyy/mm/dd','nls_calendar=persian') as REGISTRATION_DATE , t2.MOBILE as mobile , t1.VOUCHER_NO as voucher_number
                             FROM Table1 t1
                             INNER JOIN table2 t2
                             ON T1.a= T2.b
                             Where to_number(to_char(to_date(t2.REGISTRATION_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyymmdd','nls_calendar=persian')) between {$start} and {$end}
                             order by 1) WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

I want to paginate outputs and show them on a blade file. How I can do that?

Comment: Did you try using eloquent ? This is hard if you are using sql like this

Comment: No we dont have Eloquent for queries like this. there is an Oracle database and we should get data from it via query